# How can I get the DPI 2 different percentage monitor?

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is that I don't know how to get correct DPI when the primary monitor percentage is 150% and the second monitor is 100% and when I start my project and switch the window from 1 to 2. When switching the window state I get the DPI but I trying but de DPI is standard 144 not changing.

This is my code:

```
public static void GetDpi(this System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen, DpiType dpiType, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY)
{
  var pnt = new System.Drawing.Point(screen.Bounds.Left + 1, screen.Bounds.Top + 1);
  var mona = MonitorFromPoint(pnt, 2/*MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST*/);
  GetDpiForMonitor(mona, dpiType, out dpiX, out dpiY);
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint([In]System.Drawing.Point pt, [In]uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetDpiForMonitor([In]IntPtr hmonitor, [In]DpiType dpiType, [Out]out uint dpiX, [Out]out uint dpiY);
```

Method calling:

```
uint x = 0, y = 0;
foreach (var screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
{
  if (screen.DeviceName == currentMonitor.Name)
  {
    screen.GetDpi(currentMonitor.MonitorHandle,DpiType.Angular, out x, out y);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/declaring-managed-apps-dpi-aware

Answer (score 0):

By default your application is set to be System DPI Aware. You need to set it to be PerMonitor DPI Aware. There are now multiple ways to do this some of which depend on what version of Windows is currently running. One way to resolve would be to add the following into your application's manifest:

```
 <dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware>
```

If you are running on Windows 10, you could also try calling:

```
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE);
```

when the app starts up.

Good luck.